# nslookup returns SERVFAIL error from local DNS

Tags: nginx, dns-zone, docker-compose, reverse-dns, ubuntu-22.04

I'm configuring Nginx and local DNS settings on  Ubuntu 22.04.

The DNS server running on Docker has an error. When resolving a domain name, the Docker DNS server returns, SERVFAIL.

`nslookup ns.main.com`

```
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused
Server:         192.168.1.1
Address:        192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find ns.main.com: NXDOMAIN
```

The first issue occurred building the Docker containers using docker-compose, getting an error when trying to start them up with docker-compose up. The error indicated that port 53 was already in use by systemd-resolved on my Ubuntu host.

I was able to resolve this conflict and get the containers running by following the steps outlined in [Ubuntu: How To Free Up Port 53, Used By systemd-resolved](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/07/ubuntu-how-to-free-up-port-53-used-by.html) which helped release port 53 from systemd-resolved.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::1%3
search .
```

**sudo lsof -i :53**

```
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 4079 juan  372u  IPv6 116841      0t0  UDP *:domain
```

I'm still unsure of the correct approach to the failure. Some information indicates that IPv6 may be causing the issues and that I should avoid using it, but I don't know if that's the right move. I don't know the root cause.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    # ports:
    #   - 53:53
    #   - 53:53/udp
    volumes:
      - ./dns/var/log/named.log:/var/log/named.log
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
```

**dns/Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add bind openrc
RUN rc-update -u named
```

**dns/named.conf**

```
options {
    directory "var/bind";
    allow-transfer { "none"; };
    allow-query { any; };
    listen-on { any; };
};

zone "main.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/main.com";
};
```

**dns/zone/main.com**

```
$ttl 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.main.com. hostmaster.main.com.(
                    202 ; Serial
                    600 ; Refresh
                    3600 ; Retry
                    12378237) ; Expire

@       IN      NS  ns.main.com.
ns      IN      A   127.0.0.1
```

**nginx/conf.d/default.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ns.main.com;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/main;
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

**nginx/Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./html /usr/share/nginx/html
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y procps
```

Comment: Check the log of the DNS daemon, it should have more information about the error.

Comment: Hey, first thank you for commenting to my issue here. I'm searching on Google, how to check the log of the DNS daemon but can't find the right instructions. Would you like to lend me a hand on how to check the log of the DNS daemon? Thanks!

Comment: Logging depends on the distribution used in the container. Bind logs to system log, and it depends on distro configuration where the actual log file is. Usually logs are in `/var/log`.

Comment: I added a line "- ./dns/var/log/named.log:/var/log/named.log" under the volume section for the DNS service in the Dockerfile, intending to check the log file. However, that log file does not exist. The DNS service is using the Alpine Linux distributuon. When I perform a nslookup for ns.main.com, I am getting a "Non-authoritative answer".

Comment: You need to find where the system log is for the container, and look into that. What the exact filename depends on the configuration of logging in the container.

Comment: welcome juanthehuman, what is your business relationship in here? what has this DNS issue to do with your nginx?

Comment: thanks djdomi, I was hoping to fix this DNS issue I'm experiencing. I'm following a tutorial on YT about nginx. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 on my host machine and I think that I've misconfigured the DNS container from the Docker that's why when I test nslookup to the domain "ns.main.com" it returns SERVFAIL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your repeated assistance, I was able to get it working correctly. There was an error in the zone file located at "dns/zone/main.com", but I have now fixed that issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't See you mapping a network,by default dicker creates it own network

A workaround could also be including `network_mode:host`in your docker compose
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

For the DNS Part I would also use the official docker image
https://hub.docker.com/r/internetsystemsconsortium/bind9

---

Static ip

```
`version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
      - ./nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    networks:
      dns:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.2

  dns:
    build:
      context: ./dns/
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
    volumes:
      - ./dns/var/log/named.log:/var/log/named.log
      - ./dns/named.conf:/etc/bind/named.conf
      - ./dns/zone/:/etc/bind/zone/
    command: named -c /etc/bind/named.conf -g -u named
    networks:
      dns:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5

networks:
  dns:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 10.5.0.0/24
          gateway: 10.5.0.1`
```

---

Comment: I tried the workaround network_mode: host in my docker compose, Now nslookup returns a different error message: 
communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused. Why 127.0.0.1 cannot resolved ns.main.com? My code is exactly the same in the tutorial on YT. updated the question/thread.

Comment: I have added an edit to assign a static ip using a custom network. DNS is a service where static ip is recommend